# How do I program a serial EEPROM IC using a raspberry Pi?

Tags: gpio, serial

I am trying to program the [25L12835F Serial EEPROM](http://www.macronix.com/QuickPlace/hq/PageLibrary4825740B00298A3B.nsf/h_Index/3F21BAC2E121E17848257639003A3146/%24File/MX25L12835F,%203V,%20128Mb,%20v1.2.pdf) with the firmware of the Pineapple WiFi router. I have the u-boot.bin file from Alfa. I have tried a programmer from eBay, but the software is unable to recognize the EEPROM chip.

I am considering hooking this IC to the headers of the Raspberry Pi. Can anyone tell me the right signals to connect? I believe this is an SPI chip. How will the chip appear to the raspberry pi? Can I count on seeing a `/dev/mtd0`? and just `dd if=uboot.bin of=/dev/mtd0` on my raspberry pi?

Comment: EEPROM programmer on ebay costs $10, maybe $15 -- please, get one and program whatever you like...

Comment: I think he said he tried one of ebay but it didn't work? Lord Loh. No you can just dump it like that you need software like avrdude to write, verify the code. Otherwise you will have hell if something goes wrong.

Comment: @ppumkin there's more that one programmer on ebay, and yes, sometimes they might be incompatible, especially if the price is well below $10

Comment: Suunds like an answer? :)

Comment: Yes. the $15 ebay programmer did not work. I am not buying a $100 programmer for a $45 router! Will AVR dude work with an SPI EEPROM? I did try flashrom from flashrom.org, but that did not work either - it did not detect a chip. Which makes me suspect that my wiring was incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Quick check on the datasheet reveals that the memory chip is in fact SPI-compatible device.

The RaspberryPi have hardware SPI support. Relevant pins on the GPIO header are: #19 (MOSI), #21 (MISO), #23 (SCLK). After connecting these three pins plus VCC (**3.3V**! not the 5V one, as the memory chip works with a supply voltage in range 2.7 - 3.6V) and GND to the memory chip, you could talk to the chip using either C (using eg [wiringPi](https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/spi-library/)) or [Python](http://www.adafruit.com/blog/2013/01/11/spi-python-hardware-spi-for-raspi-from-python-piday-raspberrypi-raspberry_pi/) using communication protocol described in chapter 9 of the datasheet.

I'm not aware of any *simplified* way of making this work, you are on your own with writing the programming software.

Comment: I enabled the SPI module in the kernel and tried to look for a device under `/dev/mtd**`. I also tried the flashrom - http://www.flashrom.org/RaspberryPi tool and nothing showed up. I assumed that I either wired wrong, the chip was dead, linux problems.

Comment: Flashrom.org seems to be a good direction to get it working, unfortunately your eeprom is not on the list of supported chips. Closest thing seems to be MX25L12805. Try to ask flashrom devs on support for your chip.

Answer (score 0):

It's Serial EEPROM, it won't appear as `/dev/mtd**` (it appears as `/sys/bus/spi/device/spi0.1/eeprom` if you connect Chip Select to CS1 on RPi)

To get Serial EEPROM working, you need to build custom kernel with custom boardconfig (since Raspberry Pi doesn't use Device-Tree in default yet.)

[Boardconfig modification example](http://mikroskeem.insomnia247.nl/linux/raspberrypi-patches/mtdflash.patch):

```
diff --git a/arch/arm/mach-bcm2708/bcm2708.c b/arch/arm/mach-bcm2708/bcm2708.c
--- a/arch/arm/mach-bcm2708/bcm2708.c
+++ b/arch/arm/mach-bcm2708/bcm2708.c
@@ -550,8 +550,8 @@ static struct spi_board_info bcm2708_spi_devices[] = {
        .chip_select = 0,
        .mode = SPI_MODE_0,
    }, {
-       .modalias = "spidev",
-       .max_speed_hz = 500000,
+       .modalias = "m25p80",
+       .max_speed_hz = 5000000,
        .bus_num = 0,
        .chip_select = 1,
        .mode = SPI_MODE_0,
```

I replaced `spidev` with `m25p80`, so You need to replace `spidev` with `at25`

You may need to adjust speed too.

EDIT: To write, do `cat uboot.bin > /sys/bus/spi/device/spi0.1/eeprom`